Flutter app not working properly on iOS Simulators
I am facing a very strange issue. I have a Flutter application which I am developing on a MacBook Pro (macOS Sonoma Version 14.4.1 (23E224)) and the app works fine on my Android Emulator and iPhone 12 Pro physical device.
The problem is with iPhone/iPad simulators where strange artefacts (different coloured shapes that distort the UI) appear as soon as I start using the app, and the more I navigate around and the app starts loading and fetching data the more intense these artefacts get until the app becomes completely unresponsive and the UI goes black. At this point I have to kill the app from VS Code or Xcode (depends on from where I build it each time, I tried both ways and form the terminal).
The strange thing is that this only happens on iOS simulators and that it didn't used to happen before. I am not sure when it started, but I tried also different branches of my code base and it happens for all of them. I even tried very early ones that I am sure that they used to work fine without this issue, and now they exhibit the same behaviour.
I tired running older branches that did not exhibit this issue but all of them now seem to be affected. I tested on at least these simulators: iPhone 15 Pro Max & iPhone 15 Pro with iOS 17.4 and iOS 17.2, iPhone 15 iOS 17.2, iPhone 14 Pro iOS 16.4, iPad Pro 6th generation iOS 17.4 and all of them exhibit this issue.
Has anyone come across this behaviour? How can I troubleshoot this issue and make sure it is due to the simulator and not my code?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

After a lot of searching, code refactoring and trying different iOS simulators and iOS versions, the issue seems to be with the Impeller rendering engine, because when I run my app on an iOS simulator using: flutter run --no-enable-impeller then it works as expected and similar to when running on Android or physical iPhone device.
